# Como faço para detectar um clique fora de um elemento?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Eu tenho alguns menus HTML, que mostro quando um usuário clica nesses menus. 
Eu gostaria de esconder esses elementos quando o usuário clica **fora** da área dos menus.

Como poderia fazer isso?

Comment: evento `onfocusout` ativa quando você remove o foco de algum elemento.

Answer (score 1):

adicione uma classe .menus e depois no jquery:

```
$('body').on('click', function () { // Pega o clique
    if (!$(this).hasClass('menus')) { //Se o objeto clicado não possuir a classe, então o clique foi fora dos menus
        $('.menus').hide(); // esconde os menus
    }
});
```